# Multidimensional Array Prev Next with PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, pagination

I'm new to PHP and have been at this for days with no luck. I want to identify the current page, and then have a link for plus one and minus one to do Prev-Next links.

The array is based on .md files in a folder. It can grow or shrink as I add blog posts. This is the current test array (minus other key-value pairs):

```
 $totalPages =  Array
(
    [0] => TD_Page Object
        (
            [keyword] => art
        )

    [1] => TD_Page Object
        (
            [keyword] => but
        )

    [2] => TD_Page Object
        (
            [keyword] => car
        )

    [3] => TD_Page Object
        (
            [keyword] => dat
        )

    [4] => TD_Page Object
        (
            [keyword] => eek
        )

    [5] => TD_Page Object
        (
            [keyword] => fit
        )
```

Since keywords act as the page URI via PHP routing, I want the end result to look conceptually something like this:

```
<a href="/blog/<?= echo next($keyword) ?>">Prev</a> 
<a href="/blog/<?= echo prev($keyword) ?>">Prev</a>
```

I want to check for the current page, then add a pointer to up or down one in the array. If it's the first or last post, then no link will appear for the corresponding prev or next link.

Comment: How are you identifying the current page? Also is this for a menu?

Comment: Current page is routed there via keyword in the URI.

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) then [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search) to find the index. then -/+ on that.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$data = [
    (object)['keyword' => 'art'],
    (object)['keyword' => 'but'],
    (object)['keyword' => 'car'],
    (object)['keyword' => 'dat'],
    (object)['keyword' => 'eek'],
    (object)['keyword' => 'fit']
];

$current = array_search('car', array_column($data, 'keyword'));

echo 'Current:'.$data[$current]->keyword.PHP_EOL;
echo 'Next:'.$data[$current+1]->keyword.PHP_EOL;
echo 'Prev:'.$data[$current-1]->keyword.PHP_EOL;
```

**Result:**

```
Current:car
Next:dat
Prev:but
```

https://3v4l.org/lOZ8e

Don't forget to check that it has a next or previous link, with `isset()` etc.

Comment: Thanks, I need to explain more.

Comment: Thanks again, Lawrence. This works, but only if I tell it what variable we are on. I am trying to dynamically determine which keyword we're viewing, and then prev-next from there. The array can grow or shrink, and keywords are wildcards, so the code needs to look at the entire array. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add all your code to the question, it seems the goal post has moved. I have answered based upon the provided array and 2 lines of code and the comment *Current page is routed there via keyword in the URI.* you would need to change to `array_search($_GET['param'],` but you also dont show the rewrites and Nowhere does it mention wildcards

Comment: or just make a new question